# Detect amount of textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Window which generates Textboxes and checkboxes of the columns in my Database: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXvSF.png)
So if I change something and click save. I want to save these. So I need a for each loop with a number of textboxes.

Is there a way to detect a number of textboxes?

Here is some code how the Textboxes and Checkboxes are created:

```
 public firmCustomerTable()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MySqlConnection connection;
        config conf = new config();
        connection = new MySqlConnection(conf.connection_string);
        DataTable schema = null;

        using (var con = new MySqlConnection(conf.connection_string))
        {
            using (var schemaCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM firmenkunden", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (var reader = schemaCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
                {
                    schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (DataRow col in schema.Rows)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.TextBox newTxt = new TextBox();
            System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox onoff = new CheckBox();

            // Add Label
            newTxt.Text = col.Field<String>("ColumnName");
            newTxt.Name = col.Field<String>("ColumnName");
            newTxt.Width = 200;


            // Add OnOff
            onoff.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            onoff.Style = (Style)FindResource("CheckBoxStyle1");
            onoff.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

            // Add To Panel
            sp.Children.Add(newTxt);
            sp.Children.Add(onoff);

       }
    }
```

Comment: I assusme they must be in a Grid or StackPanel, or some kind of Container. Should be sufficient to query the children of these and limit it to TextBoxes

Comment: How about adding some code, so we can see how the controls are created.

Comment: @R.Rusev i added some code.

Comment: Have a look at [ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In your form put 
`using System.Linq` to use extensions. Then, you can use `OfType<>` method to get all `TextBox` controls which are put on the panel, like this:

```
List<TextBox> textboxes = sp.Children.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
```

and then you can do your stuff with list of textboxes.
Also, to get count:

```
int count = textboxes.Count;
```